# aspx pages in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC3 application.In the views folder i created a folder called as reports and inside reports i added an aspx page with the name as "participantReport.aspx".
i created a master page(a normal one not the MVC3 master page) in the shared folder and used it for this aspx page.

The problem is when i type the url as "localhost:xxxx/Reports/participantReport.aspx" , i get a "Server Error in '/' Application.The resource cannot be found." message.

Further in the controller i used a function as given below:-

```
    public RedirectResult Reports()
    {
        return Redirect("~/Reports/ParticipantReport.aspx");
    }
```

How to access this page?

Answer (score 0):

There is a web.config you your views folder at default, in the web.config there is a catch all handler defined:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

So every request in that views folder will be sent to the http not found handler. The solution is to move your reports outside the views folder.